# If I (the question author) cannot see who voted to close a question, was it closed by a moderator?

Tags: support, closed-questions, closing-questions

Referring to this: [What is the single highest damage attack that can be made by one tenth level character with no assistance, support, or magic items? [closed]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/198309/what-is-the-single-highest-damage-attack-that-can-be-made-by-one-tenth-level-cha)

[image: This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers. Add details and clarify the problem being solved. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one. (Private feedback for you)]

Typically, if a question is closed, it will show 'closed by - list of names'.  I'm not sure why this is not the case for this question.

Comment: I don’t know why you can’t see it, so I won’t answer, but it was closed by five users. Can you see the user list in the [timeline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/198309/timeline)?

Answer (score 8):

#### This is working as intended. You cannot (easily) see who closed your own question

- [Can I no longer see who closed my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353946)
- [How could we improve our planned post notice improvements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332499)

> We have clear and scary examples of times when users lash out at specific closers because their question was closed or deleted. Up to and including requiring police intervention or having their employers called because of closing someone's question. This isn't OK. I'd much rather a user be angry at the system for closing their question than at a person.

> Update: We've changed the post notices for question askers so that they do not see the usernames of close voters listed - this includes askers with the close/reopen vote privilege.
>
> We considered making it so that post owners with sufficient rep could still see the list, but decided against it primarily for cost/benefit reasons: the way our code is constructed right now, a lot of other code relies on a person being classified as either a post owner or a privileged user, but not both. This separation makes sense in most places, just not in this instance. And because the likelihood of a higher-rep user having their question closed is lower (and they’re more likely to know how to access the voters if necessary), we felt that this was an appropriate tradeoff.
>
> We discussed changing the post notice language for users who do have permissions but decided to leave it as-is, so that still indicates that both the post owner and those with close/reopen vote privileges can see the names. Because post owners are still able to see who voted to close/reopen their question by going into the post history, it would be inaccurate to say that they do not have access to that information. It's merely harder to reach (and lower rep users are much less likely to find it).
>
> We think that the small change we've made is the best first step in solving this problem. It makes it much more difficult for users who might be angry to lash out at voters, while still being honest with voters that the post owner can see who voted on their post. And we're definitely open to feedback on this approach!

Comment: I don't know whether it'll be consolidation or just amusing, but moderators aren't exempt from this either.

Comment: @Someone_Evil “Up to and including requiring police intervention or having their employers called because of closing someone's question.” People are wild.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov To be fair, there are entire careers based on Overflow.

Comment: @Someone_Evil Can you see close voters in the question timeline? I can see who closed my own posts there.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Yes. Everyone can see who closed a question by going to the timeline, including non-logged in readers.